# Run more timelines at the same

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to learn something in WPF in window by code not XAML. I would like to have more timelines to transform object (rectangle) at the same time. I mean RotateTransform and TransitionTransform to be called by one command.

```
    Rectangle aRectangle = new Rectangle();
    aRectangle.Width = 30;
    aRectangle.Height = 30;
    aRectangle.Fill = Brushes.Blue;

    TransformGroup g = new TransformGroup();

    RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    TranslateTransform animatedTranslateTransform = new TranslateTransform();


    g.Children.Add(rotateTransform);
    g.Children.Add(animatedTranslateTransform);

    aRectangle.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    aRectangle.RenderTransform = g;

    PathGeometry animationPath = new PathGeometry();
    PathFigure pFigure = new PathFigure();
    pFigure.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    seg.Points.Add(new Point(0, 100));
    seg.Points.Add(new Point(100, 100));
    seg.Points.Add(new Point(100, 50));
    seg.Points.Add(new Point(50, 50));
    pFigure.Segments.Add(seg);
    animationPath.Figures.Add(pFigure);
    animationPath.Freeze();

    DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateXAnimation =
        new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
    translateXAnimation.PathGeometry = animationPath;
    translateXAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    translateXAnimation.Source = PathAnimationSource.X;


    DoubleAnimationUsingPath translateYAnimation =
        new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
    translateYAnimation.PathGeometry = animationPath;
    translateYAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    translateYAnimation.Source = PathAnimationSource.Y;
    DoubleAnimation translateAngle = new DoubleAnimation(0, 360, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
```

If I use this code everything works ok:

```
    rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, translateAngle);
    animatedTranslateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, translateXAnimation);
    animatedTranslateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, translateYAnimation);
```

But it seems very complex and I try to get any idea how run all animation together. I have tried Storyboard but I must use Canvas.Left and Top to move it and also rotation does not function.

Comment: creating or manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is strongly discouraged. You should really be learning XAML instead.

Comment: @HighCore - In general I agree but when you need to customize the animations a lot depending on data it might be easier to write C# code instead of having a lot of bindings in XAML.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd which is not the OP's case right now. Avoiding XAML in WPF is like avoiding LINQ in C#.

Comment: @HighCore - Although off-topic: I avoid Linq when I need speed but in general I use it. His question is clear: he wants to know how to do it in XAML.

Comment: Could a [ParallelTimeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-simplify-animations-by-using-child-timelines) be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run animations in parallel is by adding them all to a storyboard and start the storyboard. This can be done in C# and in XAML.

Example in [XAML from this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364529/Animation-using-Storyboards-in-WPF):

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sb" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myrect" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="1" To="350" 
                     Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myrect" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="1" To="250" 
                     Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:1"/>

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myrect" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="250" To="1" 
                     Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:2"/>

    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myrect" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="350" To="1" 
                     Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:3"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Example in [C# from this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation.From = 100;
myDoubleAnimation.To = 200;
myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, myRectangle.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.WidthProperty));

ColorAnimation myColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
myColorAnimation.From = Colors.Blue;
myColorAnimation.To = Colors.Red;
myColorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myColorAnimation, "MySolidColorBrush");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myColorAnimation, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty)); 
Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
myStoryboard.Children.Add(myColorAnimation);

myStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

Comment: I dont need to know how to do it in XAML. I need to know how to do it in code. I need to know if there is any chance to put those BeginAnimation methods to the one simple method. I never did it in C# but in JavaFX when I want to run more transitions together I simple put them to ParallelTransition and invoke Start method, that was all. I need to move object over path and rotate it when it moving.

Comment: @joziff - as I stated: put the animations in a single storyboard and the storyboard. That will start both or all animations. The storyboard is a kind of parallel timeline.

Comment: @joziff the xaml and code examples in my answer are not linked or depending on each other. Anything in xaml can be done in code. You can ignore the xaml if you want